# How can I access an instance outside of the method it was created in?

Tags: c#

I am working on a console app that transmits OutGauge data to an Arduino, but I'm stuck with the problem described below.

Here's the top of my code:

```
using System;
using InSimDotNet.Out;
using ArduinoDriver;
using ArduinoUploader.Hardware;
using ArduinoDriver.SerialProtocol;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var driver = new ArduinoDriver.ArduinoDriver(ArduinoModel.NanoR3, true);
```

I need to access `driver` (which I created in the `Main` method) in `outgauge_PacketReceived()`.
To be specific, I need to use its `Send()` method.

```
static void outgauge_PacketReceived(object sender, OutGaugeEventArgs e)
{
    //I need driver.Send() here.
}
```

Comment: Make `driver` a member of your class as `static MyDriverClass driver = ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declare `driver` at the class level:

```
static ArduinoDriver _driver;

static void Main()
{
   _driver = new ArduinoDriver.ArduinoDriver(ArduinoModel.NanoR3, true);
   //...
}
```

You declare it as a class member, then still instantiate it in `Main`

Answer (score 0):

Declare it outside of Main, like this:

```
using System;
using InSimDotNet.Out;
using ArduinoDriver;
using ArduinoUploader.Hardware;
using ArduinoDriver.SerialProtocol;

class Program
{
    ArduinoDriver driver;

    static void Main()
    {
    driver = new ArduinoDriver.ArduinoDriver(ArduinoModel.NanoR3, true);
```